# In Visual Studio 2022 not able to set icon for MSI package and .net framework

Tags: package, frameworks, visual-studio-2022

I am not able to set icon for MSI package in Visual Studio 2022 dropdown is not working for icon and .net framework version[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYbaO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WGD6.png)

Need to add icon for my MSI package and change .net framework version